# Azure - VMSS - Data disk

Tags: azure

I have created a vmss and added an addition Fisk from Fisk storage but it’s not available in the VM’s disk management as we usually get for normal VM(not from VMSS)

So how I can attach the new data disk on my VM from vmss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of tutorials (in the official docs) available for this:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-use-disks-cli
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-use-disks-powershell
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-attached-disks

powershell cmd:

```
# Get scale set object
$vmss = Get-AzVmss `
          -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" `
          -VMScaleSetName "myScaleSet"

# Attach a 128 GB data disk to LUN 2
Add-AzVmssDataDisk `
  -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss `
  -CreateOption Empty `
  -Lun 2 `
  -DiskSizeGB 128

# Update the scale set to apply the change
Update-AzVmss `
  -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" `
  -Name "myScaleSet" `
  -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
```

cli:

```
az vmss disk attach \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --name myScaleSet \
  --size-gb 128
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link for ARM template Data Disk [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachinescalesets/createorupdate#create-a-scale-set-with-empty-data-disks-on-each-vm.)

You can find detailed options of how to use data disk and use prepopulated data disk here:
[Azure virtual machine scale sets and attached data disks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-attached-disks)

[Azure VM Scale Sets attach-detach disk preview](https://github.com/Azure/vm-scale-sets/tree/master/preview/disk)